# ı want to open new connection for every query in one request using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I use entity framework 6 version with .net 6

I want to use more than one and different databases in a request made, for example, both Mssql and postgresql from the same request, and after each query I want to define a different connection address with the relevant provider again, how can I do this in dbcontext

OnConfiguring method is

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        
            if(type == 0)
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration1.GetConnectionString("Mssql"));
            if(type == 1)
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuration1.GetConnectionString("Postgres"));

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a configuration for "MsSQL" and one for "postgreSQL". Then define a subclass for each database.

This guide has a solution for your problem: https://michaelceber.medium.com/how-to-support-multiple-databases-in-entity-framework-core-1ccd24896829